# How to create a private docker volume for container with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Is there an access mode in docker that allows you to mount a host directory into a container and any files changes / addition / deletion are local to that container i.e. The host files don't change?

`:ro` does not allow any type of writing

I know I could just use `COPY` but the directory is very large and don't want to have to rebuild the image every time the directory changes.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts), where there is always a [bind propagation between the host and the container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation).

You could instead declare and use a new [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), and rsync `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-volume/_data` with your host folder whenever you want to refresh its content.

That would initially duplicate your large folders, but any data modification done in that docker volume would remain private and would not affect said original large folder on your host.